# TypeScript function argument destructuring with partial types annotation

Tags: typescript

Let's consider example:

```
function func1(num: number) {
  return num * 2;
}

function func2(by: number, num = func1(1)) {
  return num / by;
}
```

It works perfectly fine. In `func2` I don't have to manually provide a type for `num` argument since it is provided from `func1`.

But when I write `func2` in form of argument object destructuring I have to manually provide a type for `num` in `func3`:

```
function func3({ by, num = func1(1) }: { by: number, num: number }) {
  return num / by;
}
```

How to write `func3` without retyping type for `num`? Something like this (code below doesn't work):

```
function func3({ by, num = func1(1) }: { by: number }) {
  return num / by;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no better way to do this unfortunately. Ideas about improving this have been floating around for a while but the compiler team has not found a good one yet. [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) issue is the latest proposal, @RyanCavanaugh says they are giving it another try, well see what comes of it. For now you have to write the names again in the type annotation